# How to navigate on console menu (pdmenu) over SSH from Python?

Tags: python, ssh, menu, navigation

I have to test pseudo-graphical menu (`pdmenu`) available on remote machine over `SSH`. Best examples of menu like my are `mc`, `htop` or `tzconfig`, but they are much more complicated.
Just in any case I don't have any idea how to read this menu and navigate thought it.
In my project `paramiko` wrapper is used, but I can switch to `pexpect` or `subprocess` directly (`pexpect` is a wrapper for `subprocess`).
My goal is to be able to **send** **arrow keys** to menu, find (or read text in) **highlighted line**, send **enter**, **space**, **escape**, detect and send text into **text field**s. Is it **possible**?
I'd rather solution to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. However, you'll have to parse the ascii responses (stream) to find all the elements that you need (e.g. highlighted chars) which might not be trivial and terminal dependant.

Here's a list of [ASCII control chars](http://www.asciitable.com/). For example, `ESC` would be `\x1b`, `Space` would be `\x20`, `Enter` would be `\r`.

Special keys and colors are expressed as [ANSI-Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). For example, `right arrow` would be `\x1b[C`, `left arrow` would be `\x1b[D`, `up arrow` would be `\x1b[A` and `down arrow` would be `\x1b[B`. `Highlighted` or `inverted` text would be prefixed with `\x1b[7m`, `blinking` text would be prefixed with `\x1b[5m` and so on.

Talking about paramiko, you'll most likely have to `ssh.invoke_shell()` and continuously receive from that channel while evaluating what you received in order to know what is actually happening in the remote menu. It should be fairly easy to detect the end of one screen by the [clear-screen escape sequence](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/ansi_escapes.html)

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
ssh.connect(ip, username='root', password="password")

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
while not chan.exit_status_ready()
    buff = ''
    while not buff.endswith('\x1b[2J'):
        resp = chan.recv(1) # tweak, bigger chunks, use select.
        buff += resp
    # buff hold data up to clear-screen
    # evaluate screen, send keystrokes to navigate
    chan.send('\x1b\r')    # ESC
```

This should get you started.

Comment: I've just modified your solution a bit: a) it is better to verify length of remaining buffer by `len(chan.in_buffer)` b) `ESC` char is '\x1b'. Thanks a lot!